# How do I optimize the SQL for this Django view?

Tags: python, sql, django, query-optimization

I'm writing a Django view that queries a list of objects from a database along with some info from a related field. The issue is that the database is doing 10 queries on 7 objects. Here's the code:

Template code:

```
{% for resource in results %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{resource.url}}"> {{resource.url}}
                 {{resource.stats_set.values.0.avg}}</a>
<!-- truncated, the rest of the template just generates a form and 
 isn't causing any unnecessary sql -->
{% endfor %}
```

View code:

```
class ResourceList(generic.ListView):
    model = Submissions
    context_object_name = 'results'
    template_name = 'url_list.html'
```

And the necessary models:

```
class Submissions(models.Model):
    LEVEL = (
        ('Introductory', 'Introductory'),
        ('Intermediate', 'Intermediate'),
        ('Academic', 'Academic'),
    )

    MEDIA_TYPE = (
        ('HTML', 'HTML'),
        ('PDF', 'PDF'),
        ('Video', 'Video'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    tags = models.ForeignKey(MajorTags, default=0)
    level = models.CharField(choices=LEVEL, max_length=25)
    media_type = models.CharField(choices=MEDIA_TYPE, max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url

class Stats(models.Model):
    url = models.ForeignKey(Submissions)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    avg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    std_dev = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url.url + " " + str(self.avg)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url.url + " " + str(self.avg)
```

The root of the issue is the `{{resource.stats_set.values.0.avg}}` bit. The problem is that if I try to do `queryset = Submissions.objects.all().select_related('avg')` I get an error saying the only option is for `select_related()` is `tags` which makes sense because that's the only field in the `Submissions` model that has a foreign key. My database structure is fairly well locked in at this point, so **I can't change the database**. I also **can't query `Stats`** and do a reverse from there because **I need to get data that doesn't have stats yet.**

How do I reduce the number of SQL queries I'm running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) which is used to make efficient queries concerning reverse foreign keys or many-to-many relationships:

From the docs:

> **prefetch_related()**
>
> Returns a QuerySet that will automatically retrieve, in a single
>   batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.

```
def get_queryset(self,*args,**kwargs):
     return Submissions.objects.all().prefetch_related('stats_set')
```

It will require an additional query, but the idea is that it will get all of the related information at once, instead of once per `Submissions` object.

On a side note it's recommended to use the *singular* of a noun for the model class name: `Submission` instead of `Submissions`.